# handling huge size of data using arraylist

Tags: java, performance

I have got an assignment question in java.

I have a text file in the size of GBs. Read it, and find the number of occurrence of each word in that file and display it like [<< word >> - <>].

Best case would be all the words are same. so i will display that word with no of occurrence
but consider the worst case like words present in the file are unique. so i need to display all the words with occurrence as 1.

How to handle this huge list of data ? Do we have any solution for this ?

Comment: what have you tried? What problem did you encounter with your code? Post that code.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, writing Map-Reduce program in java could be the best approach for this. 
Here is an example for word count program using Map-Reduce paradigm : [Word Count Example](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount)

Other approach could be perform this using recursive read/write operations.
Create a Map (one map per alphabet) so that you can have 26 maps with you. Put words in appropriate maps depending on the starting alphabets. When certain map size is reached, write all the words from that map along with its incremented count to a file with some identification to know which words it contains. Once you have read all the words from your file (size in GB's), read back the files from disk and calculate the word count. this will involve some IO, but I think will no cause any memory related issues.